# Как автоматизировать заполнение List?

Tags: c#

Как я могу создать к примеру 100 `List<string>`, заполнить их значениями от 1 до 50 000, но не больше 500 значений на один?

т.е в ручную у меня пока так..:

```
List<string> All = new List<string>();
List<string> F500 = new List<string>();
List<string> F1000 = new List<string>();
List<string> F1500 = new List<string>();

 public void add2l()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            F500.Add(i.ToString());
            F1000.Add(i + 500.ToString());
            F1500.Add(i + 1000.ToString());
        }
        string joinedF500 = string.Join(",", F500);
        string joinedF1000 = string.Join(",", F1000);
        string joinedF1500 = string.Join(",", F1500);

        All.Add(joinedF500);
        All.Add(joinedF1000);
        All.Add(joinedF1500);
    }
```

> На выходе будет:
>
> All[0] = 0..499
>
> All[1] = 500..999
>
> и т.д

Comment: Я не совсем понял. По коду видно, что в 'All' у вас строки, в которых числа разделены запятыми. Так и должно быть? Или все таки нужно N 'List<string>' по K 'string' в каждом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант аналогичный вашему по результату, но немного быстрее и не требует лишней памяти

```
int lists = 100;
int values = 500;
List<string> All = new List<string>(lists);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < lists; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < values; j++)
    {
        sb.Append(values * i + j);
        if (j < values-1)
            sb.Append(',');
    }
    All.Add(sb.ToString());
    sb.Clear();
}
```

Comment: огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Список списков?

```
List<List<string>> All = new List<List<string>>(); // список всех списков
for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < 100; listIndex++) { // создаём 100 List<string>
     var list = new List<string>(); // создаём новый список
     for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) { // добавляем в него 500 элементов
         list.Add((1 + i + listIndex * 500).ToString()); // со смещением, зависящим от индекса списка
     }
     All.Add(list);
}
// в All  теперь 100 списков по 500 элементов
```

Comment: если известны длины списков, лучше зафиксировать их при вызове конструктора. Ресайз массива не слишком дешевая операция, даже с учетом всех возможных оптимизаций на низком уровне.